# Android custom Text To Speech

Tags: android, text-to-speech

We're using Androids default TTS engine. Unfortunately we got feedback from a lot of users that the voice sounds really impolite.
Since we're using the default TTS, the quality highly depends on the device that the user owns.

Are there other (free) TTS engines we can use in our app?
OR is there a way to install better Android TTS without leaving the App on the client?

Comment: Alternative TTS engines are available in the Play Store. Why would they  have to be installed without leaving the app? Isn't it best to just let the user decide which TTS engine to use? If you want to bundle for example [Acapela's TTS engine](http://www.acapela-group.com/acapela-for-android/) as a part of your own app, then that means paying some license royalties. All the good ones (like Acapela TTS Voices) probably cost some money.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's an app for businesses and they usually buy tablets, put our app on it and hand it out for the users in a kiosk-mode. We can only advise our customers, but do not have full control over how they configure the tablets. Which currently means we have limited control over the UX, too. If our app could have TTS bundled in, we could assure a minimum quality on all the devices.

Comment: I see. Well, my understanding is that you could enforce the use of for example Acapela's TTS engine in your app. with their Android SDK and always have the same level of speech quality. I haven't tried that myself though and it's probably not your only (or cheapest) choice. Especially if you don't need to support a large number of languages.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out.